# Client/Server Pygame execution hangs

Tags: python, server, client

I am VERY new to client/server programming and am trying to build a multi-player game to build my skills.

Each client sends a string to the server (for example, their "move") and the server interprets this, does what it needs to do and then returns a "game" object. On the client side, each time I retrieve that game object, I check for stuff (for example, is it my turn) and act accordingly. In order to know if it is a client's turn, I am constantly "getting" the game object.

All of this works fine with console output (or at least it appeared to), but once I started using Pygame, with 4 clients running (to simulate 4 connected players) I see that the screen updates ok for the player whose turn it is (and even for the next client although that client soon hangs until it is their turn) but subsequent clients are "hanging" right from the start.

I have done a bunch of research into threading and parallel processing and other but it has become clear to me that I don't even understand the fundamental problem I am facing.

Is the technique of passing the game object to clients the problem? Should I somehow be running the network communications or the pygame stuff in a separate thread?

I can, of course, post my code, but not knowing the implementation issue I am facing, I am not sure what to post. Could somebody point out the likely problem with my approach based on the above info?

Comment: Im no expert, but also wanted to build a multiplayer game with pygame, i made snake but with multiple players, i way i did it was the server has all the snakes and did all the calculations/collisions, everything, i had a `time.sleep(0.0001)` then sent all the snakes to every player. the client only drew the screen and sent any action (like direction change) to the the server, not sure what type of game you are making and if this applies but i hope this helps.

Comment: @TheBigKahuna I was also trying to build something similar, simple tictactoe game, but I got problems with clients constantly blocking in main loop. Can you please tell me how you solved sending data from client to server without blocking. I tried with threads and asyncio but have not achived anything..

Comment: I used the [PodSixNet](https://github.com/chr15m/PodSixNet) library which handled most of it. i just had a function that got called when received an update

Comment: I did not know about this library. But it looks like it will solve my problem. Thank you very much.